# wordpress ssh2 update Public and Private keys incorrect

Tags: wordpress, ssh, updates

I'm trying to setting up wordpress for update via ssh2 I followed the steps of [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu)
But I can't get it working. Always same error "Public and Private keys incorrect for (user)"
I have been searching in internet trying to resolve it but nothing seems to work.

Anybody could help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, that's an unnecessarily complicated way of doing things.

Comment: Any ideas to make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

I get it working on withouth keys with user and password for ssh conection and libssh2. Easier to set up